# 502 Bad Gateway Error In Nginx using Phalcon and jQuery on submit

Tags: unity-game-engine, phalcon, nginx-config, fpm, http-status-code-502

I'm having some trouble resolving a 502 error on an NGINX server using the Phalcon 4.0.x Framework. Specifically on forms that send Ajax data to the PHP controller. These do not seems to arrive, but the Ajax it is working.

I have explored several alternatives without success.

The NGINX configuration is as follows:

```
location / {
        # Matches URLS $_GET['_url']
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
        #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Request-With' always;
        #add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }
```

I checked if jQuery is working and
I changed NGINX configuration file and tested if PHP-FPM es working.

Answer (score 0):

A 502 error usually means that Nginx is unable to contact the upstream PHP server. Based off what you’ve said, I believe your normal resolution is working. You can confirm this by simply changing your index.php on an Ajax request to have just `echo “hello world”; exit;` and confirm it working.

That said I do see a 502 error in one other instance specifically. That is when an error is occurring in the processing that causes a segmentation fault or stacking errors. This is a bit trickier to figure out but there are several things you can do. The first is enable logging by configuring php with `log_errors = on` and `error_log = /temp/php.log` And see what the output is. The alternative, and typically better in my opinion is using xdebug to step the code line by line until you find the error. You can also use profiling or tracing in xdebug, but I personally find stepping the code the easiest to get to the direct cause. Once you find the cause, you can go from there in resolving it.

I will say this, if it ends up being a seg fault, you will need to use gdb to debug, which I will not go into here.